# FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/path/to/file.png._00_'

Tags: python, google-drive-api, ipython, google-colaboratory

Im using this to get the newest created file in a directory.

```
max_file[0] = [x for x in os.listdir(_dir) if os.path.getctime(os.path.join(_dir, x)) == max([os.path.getctime(os.path.join(_dir, i)) for i in os.listdir(_dir)])]
```

But what I sometimes get returned is "path/to/file/0001.png._00_" which is weird because the pictures dont have underscores at all. Sometimes it works fine. I suspect it is like this because the image is to new or it gets appended because google drive has not uploaded the files yet?

Comment: Can you include more code? I have to ask, is the print out literally `path/to/file`? Because that implies that your directory path is probably wrong.

Comment: Its "path/to/file.png\_00_" With these underscores and the 00 or sometimes 01 which shouldnt be there. When I change it the variable without the udnerscores and the zeros it works fine.

Comment: **What is the rest of your code.** It seems like something is appending `_00_` to your directory but I can't guess what it is. I used your above code and redefined `_dir` to one of my directories and it ran fine.